# Getting from dynamic Request to a List

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

My code is working nicelly but I would like to know if you can suggest something more performatic to get the values frm my dynamic controls.

```
public class Obj
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public List<int> getValues (List<Obj> myList)
    {
        List<Obj> listQuatity = new List<Obj>();
        foreach (Obj item in myList)
        {
            listQuatity.Add(new Obj
                        { 
                          ID = item.ID,
                          Quantity = Request.Params["codControl" + item.ID].Trim().Equals("") 
                             ? 0 
                             : Convert.ToInt32(Request.Params["codControl" + item.ID])
                        });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged linq?

Comment: @cadrell0 maybe a solution ? Since LINQ is the greatest way to deal with lists..

Comment: LINQ to objects is no more efficient than a loop.  In fact, most of the time, it will end up performing the same foreach.  It just looks prettier and is easier maintain.  It sounds like you have an answer in mind before you asked the question.  Try not to be prejudice against answers that go a different direction.

Comment: How many items could be passed in? You think about performance just because this is a good practice or some real worst cases?

Comment: @sll Good practices.. Im doing my best to improve my knowledge about the lists subject since I use it a lot lately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no much space for optimization, your loop is pretty simple and straightforward.
One thing I would improve - caching of the `Request.Param` value instead accessing it twice:

(This could be rewritten using LINQ so would look more elegant but it would not be faster)

```
public List<int> getValues(List<Obj> myList)
{
    List<Obj> listQuatity = new List<Obj>();
    foreach (Obj item in myList)
    {
        // access it once so code would be slightly faster
        // but much clear
        var requestParam = Request.Params["codControl" + item.ID].Trim();
        listQuatity.Add(new Obj
            {
                ID = item.ID,
                Quantity = requestParam.Equals(String.Empty)
                       ? 0
                       : Convert.ToInt32(requestParam)
            });
    }
}
```

Let's see how LINQ query would look:

```
List<Obj> listQuatity =
myList.Select(i => new {
                Id = i.ID,
                Param = Request.Params["codControl" + item.ID].Trim(),
             })
      .Select(i => new Obj { 
                ID = i.Id,
                Quantity = Param.Equals(String.Empty)
                           ? 0 
                           : Convert.ToInt32(i.Param) 
            })
     .ToList();
```